# Hierarchical Taxonomy Term View

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I have a Taxonomy which looks like this:

```
Parent1
-Child1
--SubChild2
--SubChild3
-Child4
--SubChild5
--SubChild6
-Child7
Parent2
-Child8
-Child9
--SubChild10
-Child11
```

I have created a view to display all terms under a specified Parent by setting a context tid . Here you can find the exported view: http://pastebin.com/us7KnKsD

The Problem is that the view only shows the terms which have sub-children.

How can I also display the terms which doesn't have sub-children?
Is it possible with views? In php I would just create some recursive function...

Comment: Isn't that that you set `Require this relationship` in the relationship setup dialog?

Comment: Changing this setting have no effect concerning to the problem

Answer (score 2):

Start your query from the Taxonomy table. Meaning select Taxonomy as your base table when creating your view. Then establish a relationship to your content from there. This will ensure your results contain all taxonomy names and then their subsequent children.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the module [Views tree](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_tree)

[image]